# SSIS 2017- Insert Update process not working

Tags: ssis, ssis-2017

I am creating a package to validate data.  I am using a lookup object, however, it is not inserting new records. It only updates records and sometimes creates duplicate records.

the original data source prior to the lookup:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
    usr.i_Record_ID,
    usr.AUDIT_JOB_ID,
    CAST(usr.id AS int) AS UserID,
    CAST(usr.created_at AS DATETIME) AS CreateDate, 
    CAST(usr.updated_at AS datetime) AS UpdateDate, 
    usr.current_sign_in_at,
    usr.last_sign_in_at,
    usr.confirmed_at,
    usr.uuid,
    usr.external_uuid,
    usr.active,
    usr.title,
    usr.first_name,
    usr.last_name,
    usr.full_name,
    usr.email,
    usr.mobile,
    usr.role_id,
    usr.position,
    usr.manager_id,
    usr.profile_id,
    usr.home_location_id,
    loc.name AS LocationName,
    usr.home_organization_id,
    org.name AS OrganizationName,
    usr.type,
    usr.start_date,
    usr.end_date,
    usr.location_ceiling_id,
    LocCeiling.name AS LocationCeilingName,
    usr.organization_ceiling_id,
    orgCeiling.name AS OrganizationCeilingName,
    usr.payroll_identifier,
    usr.Audit_Date
FROM stg.Users AS usr
    LEFT OUTER JOIN stg.Organizations AS orgCeiling
        ON orgCeiling.id = usr.organization_ceiling_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN stg.Organizations AS org
        ON org.id = usr.home_organization_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblLocations_DIM AS loc
        ON loc.id = usr.home_location_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblLocations_DIM AS LocCeiling
        ON LocCeiling.id = usr.location_ceiling_id
ORDER BY userID
```

Linked by USERID

I remove record where USERID = 1, which still exists in the original datasource, but it still does not create a new record in the new table.  What am I missing?

Thanks,

Karen

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a data flow that moves data from `stg.Users` to `tblUser_Dim` (schema unknown assuming dbo for this answer). It seems you have at least a type 1 dimension for your User but it could be type 2, 3, 6 etc.

If this were my packages, I'd say you need an a Derived Column + a Conditional Split in the data flow.

## Lookup

The Lookup should be pointing at dbo.tblUser_Dim and comparing the unique-ifier in the source system to the dimension table. I'll assume this is `usr.id` aka `USERID` based on your problem statement.

I will map the source `UserID` value to the dimension table's `UserID`. As you have already identified, you will have either a match or no match record here.

### Lookup - No Match output

The No match, path correctly routes to an OLE DB Destination which inserts the data into the target table.

### Lookup - Match Output

If there *is* a match, then you likely need to compare whether the source data is the same as the destination. Otherwise, you're constantly paying to update data that never changed. There are a host of ways to detect change and I'll defer to Step 4 in the Stairway to Integration Services for a detailed explanation but the short is that you need to compare value(s) between the source and the lookup. I'll assume that the `UpdateDate` column can be trusted to identify when the source data has changed (NB, this is rarely a valid assumption).

I find, the best way to deal with computing expressions is to make a derived column to hold the result as I will inevitably have to debug why I'm getting an unexpected result.

### Derived Column - HasChanged

I will add a new column called `HasChanged`. The purpose of this is to have a column I can reference that tells me whether we need to update the target table. It will be type of boolean, DT_BOOL. I further assume that I brought back the change column(s) in my Lookup Component and appended a _lkp suffix to them. Thus, I have `UpdateDate` from the Source Component, and `UpdateDate_lkp` from the Lookup Component.

I'll start with an expression like

```
UpdateDate != UpdateDate_lkp
```

Psuedologic - Is the update date from the source system not the same as the update date from the target table (our dimension)?  If they are different, our column will evaluate to True, otherwise, False.

## Conditional Split - change detection

From the Derived Column, you want to add a Conditional Split. The Expression you will use is our new column `HasChanged` and the output will be called `Updated Rows` (instead of Case 1).

Connect your `Update tblUser_Dim` component to this "Updated Rows" output.

## Update tblUser_Dim

This is likely the other problem with your data flow. The OLE DB Destination (or ADO.NET Destination or ODBC Destination) component is INSERT ONLY. Yes, the OLE DB Destination does support the 5 drop down item of ... custom query but it does not allow you to update data. It only sends an INSERT/INSERT BULK statement down the wire. Knowing that, you can see why you occasionally get duplicates in your target table.

There are two approaches to updating data in SSIS. For low volume change, tens to hundreds of changes, you can use an `OLE DB Command`. It will fire off a statement for every row that comes through the component. The singleton updates + only supporting the OLE DB Connection Managers is among the reasons I don't favor this approach.

The other approach is to create a custom table to hold the staged data. It's a mirror of the current tblUser_Dim but in say, the `stg` schema. After the Data Flow Completes, you'll then add an Execute SQL Task that performs the update in a set-wise fashion which is way better for the server, your performance, etc.

```
UPDATE T
SET
    first_name = S.first_name
, ....
FROM
    dbo.tblUser_Dim AS T
    INNER JOIN
        stg.tblUser_Dim AS S
        ON S.UserID = T.UserID;
```

Just be sure and have an Execute SQL Task before the data flow to clear out the values of stg.tblUser_Dim (`TRUNCATE TABLE stg.tblUser_Dim;`)

## Concluding thoughts

If the source and target data are in the same database (they can use the same Connection Manager) or are at least on the same server (assuming not Azure SQL DB), there's no reason to use a Data Flow Task to move your data about. Depending on where the SSIS package runs, you might be paying a network penalty to pull the data from Server A (source server) to Server B (SSIS package runner) only to push the data back to Server A (also the target server).

Continue using SSIS as your process orchestrator but instead of the data flow, use and Execute SQL Task and write the insert and update statements there.

```
-- Modify what needs to be changed

UPDATE T
SET
    first_name = S.first_name
, ....
FROM
    dbo.tblUser_Dim AS T
    INNER JOIN
(
-- Repeat of your source query
SELECT ....
FROM stg.Users AS usr
LEFT OUTER JOIN stg.Organizations AS orgCeiling
    ON orgCeiling.id = usr.organization_ceiling_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN stg.Organizations AS org
    ON org.id = usr.home_organization_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblLocations_DIM AS loc
    ON loc.id = usr.home_location_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblLocations_DIM AS LocCeiling
    ON LocCeiling.id = usr.location_ceiling_id
) S
        ON S.UserID = T.UserID
WHERE
    S.UpdateDate <> T.UpdateDate;


-- Add what's new
INSERT INTO dbo.tblUser_Dim
( column list here)
-- Repeat of your source query
SELECT ....
FROM stg.Users AS usr
    ....
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM dbo.tblUser_Dim AS T WHERE T.UserID = usr.id
);
```

### Reference material

Andy Leonard's series on the Stairway to SSIS, especially the incremental load pattern is exactly what you're looking for and I highly recommend everyone read it

- Step 3 https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/adding-rows-in-incremental-loads-level-3-of-the-stairway-to-integration-services
- Step 4 https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/updating-rows-in-incremental-loads-level-4-of-the-stairway-to-integration-services